# In what number of "fallah" word's permutations we see identical letters next to each other?

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many six letter words can formed with all six letters in the word "fallah" such that two identical letters are next to each other (appear consecutively)?

Is the answer given by ?: $$\dfrac{6!}{2!\cdot 2!}$$ If yes, please explain.

An example of identical letters next to each other: 'flaalh', in which both 'a's are attached, each to the other.

Comment: But 'ffalalh' is not a permutation of 'fallah'.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed it.

Comment: It is definitely not $\frac{6!}{2!2!}$ because that is the number of arrangements of `fallah` regardless of the extra condition where there must be a pair of adjacent same letters and included in that number are arrangements which violate the condition.

Comment: do we count $faallh$ twice?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Let $L$ represent the set of arrangements of `fallah` where both `l`'s **are** next to one another.

Let $A$ represent the set of arrangements of `fallah` where both `a`'s **are** next to one another.

The number of arrangements then are $|L\cup A|$

Apply inclusion-exclusion.

> To count $|L|$ instead of arranging `fallah`, instead arrange `faLah` and replace the `L` with `ll` once arranged.  Make a similar argument for counting $|A|$ and $|L\cap A|$.  Then remember that inclusion-exclusion implies $|L\cup A|=|L|+|A|-|L\cap A|$

Answer (score 0):

How many words can be formed with letters 'f', 'a', 'l' and 'h' (without repetition)?

Does that number change if you add an extra 'a' adjacent to the 'a' already part of the four letter word?

eg. falh becomes faalh

What happens if you add an extra 'l'?